# WSUS to install previous months updates on nth day of each month plus snapshot

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

Would love to hear your suggestions to accomplish the following.

I'm looking for a way for WSUS to automatically download the previous months Critical and Security updates on every 10th of the month. Prior to the updates, I'd like to somehow automate a snapshot of the VM in VMWare in case the update breaks things.

I have currently installed a standalone WSUS server (2012) that downloads from WU and I have configured 5 computer groups and assigned servers based on impact (and current manual update batches). I have assigned servers via GPO's which set the target group etc and are assigned to servers by their security group membership.

There are also non domain joined computers that i have set to point to the relevant group on the WSUS server.

I don't know how to schedule updates for each group however (limited knowledge of WSUS)

Thanks

Comment: Let say you are running this would you like it to download the updates from the previous month (month since you last ran the process) or previous month on the 10th Feb download all of Jans updates

Comment: Yes, Say it was Feb 10th, i'd like all of Dec 11th-Jan 10th's updates to be installed or even all upto Jan 10th in case any updates where missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way for WSUS to automatically download the previous
>   months Critical and Security updates on every 10th of the month

You won't be able to automatically download the previous months updates. You can only schedule updates X number of times in a day. Loading the **Update Services** Snap-In, you can find that under **Options > Synchronization Schedule**.

To choose the classification of the update, you do that under **Options > Products and Classifications**. Go to the **Classifications** tab and you should find **Critical Updates** and **Security Updates**.

[image]

> I'd like to somehow automate a snapshot of the VM in VMWare in case
>   the update breaks things.

This should already be outlined in your backup Policy/Strategy.

> I don't know how to schedule updates for each group

If you already have the Computer Groups setup, you can setup under Options > **Automatic Approvals**. You can setup rules for each of your Computer Groups. Since you want more granular control, you'll want to setup the rules, but leave the items **unchecked**. When you're ready to approve a rule, check the box and choose **Run Rule**.

[image]